# How to use an object inside an EventHandler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

That's my code inside my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000); // 1 Second
    dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dtTick);
}
```

Now after the MainPage Constractor I have and the dtTick EventHandler to DO SOMETHING and an EventHandler for a start button to make the Timer works

```
void dtTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var time = DateTime.Parse(theTimer.Text);
    time = time.AddSeconds(1);
    theTimer.Text = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     dt.Start();
}
```

So My question is how how can I make **dt.Start();** works cause it's a method called on an object that is located in my MainPage().

Comment: is this WPF or SL or what else?

Comment: it's a Windows Phone Application

Comment: Keyword is [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code behind file expose the Timer as a public/protected or private member or field.

```
private DispatcherTimer dt = null; 

public MainPage()    
{    
    InitializeComponent();    
    this.dt = new DispatcherTimer();    
    this.dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000); // 1 Second    
    this.dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dtTick);    
}    

private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
     if (this.dt != null)
              this.dt.Start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make it work this way - the `dt` declared in the constructor is scoped to just the constructor so cannot be accessed outside of there.

What you need to do is declare `dt` at the module level, then you can access it anywhere within MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public class MainPage
{

    private DispatcherTimer _dt;

    public MainPage()
    {
        _dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         _dt.Start();
    }
}
```